# Grunt in magento not compiling files

Tags: docker, magento, gruntjs

I have a problem with the local installation (docker) magento.
I tried to make some css changes, unfortunately grunt.js does not compile my files. After the "grunt watch" command has been initiated, the console displays "Waiting ..." but does not update any files. Please help :)

Comment: Did you add your theme to dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js?

Comment: Did you try grunt less ? Are you running this command from Magento directory? Did you try modify and save any CSS file in watch mode?

Answer (score 0):

@btek
Yes, I added theme.
Grunt exec command returns me warnings:

```
grunt exec:xx --force
Running "exec:xx" (exec) task
Running "clean:xx" (clean) task
>> 7 paths cleaned.

Done.


Execution Time (2018-04-19 08:12:01 UTC)
loading tasks                98ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 37%
loading grunt-contrib-clean  76ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 29%
clean:xx                    90ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 34%
Total 265ms

Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html>> Exited with code: 1.
>> Error executing child process: Error: Process exited with code 1.
Warning: Task "exec:xx" failed. Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.


Execution Time (2018-04-19 08:11:57 UTC)
loading tasks       758ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 17%
loading grunt-exec   47ms  ▇ 1%
exec:xx             3.6s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 82%
Total 4.4s
```

And grunt less:

```
grunt less:xx
Running "less:xx" (less) task
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/xx/css/styles-m.css not written because no source files were found.
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/xx/css/styles-l.css not written because no source files were found.

Done.


Execution Time (2018-04-19 08:45:14 UTC)
loading tasks               81ms  ▇▇▇ 7%
loading grunt-contrib-less  1.1s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 92%
less:xx                    12ms  ▇ 1%
Total 1.2s
```

Grunt in watch mode doesn't update my css files :(

Comment: It looks like you don't have source files. Are you using base theme? Do you have theme.less or styles.less in your theme

Comment: @btek Yes, I have _theme.less, and _typography.less in theme/web/css/source directory

Answer (score 0):

@btek sure!

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

'use strict';

/**
 * Define Themes
 *
 * area: area, one of (frontend|adminhtml|doc),
 * name: theme name in format Vendor/theme-name,
 * locale: locale,
 * files: [
 * 'css/styles-m',
 * 'css/styles-l'
 * ],
 * dsl: dynamic stylesheet language (less|sass)
 *
 */
module.exports = {
    blank: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Magento/blank',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l',
            'css/email',
            'css/email-inline'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
    luma: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Magento/luma',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
    backend: {
        area: 'adminhtml',
        name: 'Magento/backend',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-old',
            'css/styles'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
    theme: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'vendor/theme',
        locale: 'de_DE',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    }
};
```

Comment: And with one you edit? I don't see any pointing to _theme.less

Comment: The last one theme. Need I add _theme.less here?

Comment: If styles-m and styles-l don't have reference to _theme.less- yes